# DataLoader: Image size is zero

Tags: python, image, artificial-intelligence, dataloader, mediapipe

When trying to load some Images for Data Science using:

```
DataLoader.from_folder(image_path)
```

I get following error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/myName/Desktop/mp_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/data_util/image_dataloader.py", line 73, in from_folder
    raise ValueError('Image size is zero')
ValueError: Image size is zero
>>>
```

In the folder under image_path there are 3 pictures (jpg).

Why is it saying size of mage is zero?

Tank you in advance!

Comment: Sense checks: Is image_path correct? Is it an absolute path or relative? Are you running the code in the right place if it's relative? Are the images in a sensible format?

Comment: When I print image_path, I get: 
```/Users/myNAME/Desktop/annotated images```

Is this not enough?

Comment: Then it's an absolute path and it should find the images (assuming that's where the images live). What format is the dataset? What's the file extension?

Comment: Here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70244407/tensorflow-lite-image-size-is-zero-error/70246590#70246590